# Отобразить данные в Listview из firebase

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-database

Я работаю над приложением на "React-native". Я прочел много руководств, но я не нашел решения моей задачи. Мне нужно просто отобразить данные из firebase в таблице Listview, но ключи к ним находятся в параллельном узле. Вот пример структуры:

[image: структура данных firebase]

Мне нужно сделать первый запрос что бы получить ключи, а следующий - для получения и отображения данных в listview.

В данный момент все выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должно быть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что данные запрашиваются функцией componentDidMount () и вызывается один раз. У меня полный ступор, я несколько день убил и не нашел решения. Может кто нибудь подскажет правильное решение или поможет отредактровать код что бы получить желаемый результат?

Вот моя реализация, но я по ней получаю только данные из "costumers":

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  this.ref = firebase.database().ref('/customers/' + userId);
  const myDataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  });
  this.state = {
    dataSource: myDataSource
  };
}

readData(ref) {
ref.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
  var tasks = [];
  dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
    tasks.push({
      name: child.val(),
      _key: child.key
    });
  });

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tasks)
  });
});
```

}

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.readData(this.ref);
}

renderRow(rowData){
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={()=>this.pressRow(rowData)}
      underlayColor = '#dddddd'>
      <View style ={styles.row}>
       <Image
          source={require('./test_image.png')}
          style={styles.deviceImage} />
          <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>Name: {rowData.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ip}>IP: {rowData.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.user}>User: {rowData.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.backgroundMainScreen}>
  <Image style={styles.header}
    source={require('./test_avatar.png')}
    blurRadius={10}>
    </Image>
  <Image style={styles.avatar}
    source={require('./test_avatar.png')}>
    </Image>
    <View style={styles.listView}>
      <Text style={styles.nameUser}>Bill West</Text>
      <Text style={styles.street}>187 west street</Text>
      <Text style={styles.city}>New York, NY 10003</Text>
      <Text style={styles.bottomText}>last sync</Text>
    <ListView
      dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}>
   </ListView>
  </View>
  </View>
)
```

}

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hoc

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ваши запросы обернул в отдельный компонент. Два запроса надо - один для юзера, один для его компьютеров. Первый я написал, второй можно повторить по аналогии. Хотя я подозреваю, что а) есть firebase hoc библиотеки на гитхабе (надо поискать, я кажется видел) б) возможно можно денормализовать ваши данный в бд, и поместить комьютеры юзера в объект юзера напрямую, без ссылок.

Код я не тестировал, но думаю, что идея понятна

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Customer {
  CustomerName: string,
  computers: string[],
}

type CustomerQueryProps = {
    customerId: string,
}

type CustomerQueryState = {
  loading: boolean,
  error: boolean,
  customer: Customer
}

class CustomerQuery extends React.Component<CustomerQueryProps, CustomerQueryState> {

  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref(`/customers/${this.props.customerId}`)
      .on('value', value => this.setState({
        customer: value,
        loading: false,
      }))
      .on('error', err => this.setState({error: true, loading: false}));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) 
      return "Loading...";

    if (this.state.error)
      return "Error!";

    return this.props.children(this.state.customer);
  }

}



const App = () => {

  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  return (
    <CustomerQuery customerId={userId}>
      {customerData => (
        <div>
          <h1>{customer.ComputerName}</h1>
          <CustomerComputers customerId={userId}>
            {computers => (
              <div>
                {computers.map(computer => computer.name)}
              </div>
            )}
          </CustomerComputers>
        </div>
      )}
    </CustomerQuery>
  )

}
```

Денормализация БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: надеюсь помогло

Comment: По поводу вашего комментария: б) возможно можно денормализовать ваши данный в бд, и поместить комьютеры юзера в объект юзера напрямую, без ссылок. Доступ к компьютерам есть только у авторизированного юзера. Просто взять все компьютера и из низ достать необходимые не получится. Если я правильно понял вас

Comment: я обновил ответ выше, на картинке видно какую структуру бд я имел в виду. таким образом вы сможете всё доставать за один запрос. С другой стороны, это может не удовлетворить другим задачам, о которых я не знаю

Comment: Из вашего примера я понял что нужно создать отдельный JS файл и поместить этот код в него. А из моего файла Computers вызвать компонент Customer и взять у него свойства, строку CustomerName и массив computers?

Comment: я не совсем понял, что есть компонент Customer.. В общем я предложил следующее решение: под каждый отдельный запрос, который вы делаете, вы можете создать компонент-запрос, к примеру CustomerQuery, как в моём примере. Данный компонент получает все необходимые для осуществления запроса параметры (к нашем примере это customerId), делает запрос, и когда запрос выполнен - вызывает функцию-потомка, которая на входе получает результат запроса, а на выходе обычный jsx. такой подход называет render props кажется

Comment: соотв. если вам нужен ещё запрос, скажем CustomerComputersQuery, можете его написать по аналогии с CustomerQuery. - на входе customerId , внутри делается запрос и children вызываются как функция от результата запроса.

Comment: в данном конкретном случае наверное будет проще объединить два запроса в одном компоненте, так что когда выполнен первый, выполняется второй. или одновременно, но в целом лучше придерживается мелкой "компонентизации" проекта, и избегать больших и сложных компонентов/функций/файлов и тд

Comment: если не понятно обяснил, если зальёте на гитхаб, вечером смогу глянуть

Comment: К сожалению на гитхаб не могу залить, если сможете почту дать, сброшу архивом. Потому как не совсем понимаю что имеете ввиду

Comment: давайте, rasdaniil@gmail.com